# Joining 3 tables and using a left outer join with linq in EF Core 3.1.1

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have 3 tables, `Notices`, `Users`, and `Likes`. I want to get all notices with user name and information if user likes this notice.

So far I have this code, but it returns one notice multiple times (one for each like):

```
return context.notices
        .GroupJoin(context.Users, notice => notice.CreatedBy, user => user.Id, (notice, users) => new { notice, users })
        .SelectMany(group => group.users.DefaultIfEmpty(), (group, user) =>
        new
        {
            group.notice,
            user
        })
        .GroupJoin(context.Likes, noticeDto => noticeDto.notice.Id, like => like.ItemId, (noticeDto, likes) => new { noticeDto, likes })
        .SelectMany(group => group.likes.DefaultIfEmpty(), (group, like) =>
        new NoticeDto
        {
            CreatedByName = (group.noticeDto.user == null ? "" : group.noticeDto.user.FullName),
            Id = group.noticeDto.notice.Id,
            Liked = like.CreatedBy == userId,
        });
```

I also tried this code.. but I am getting an error:

```
return context.notices
                .GroupJoin(context.Users, notice => notice.CreatedBy, user => user.Id, (notice, users) => new { notice, users })
                .SelectMany(group => group.users.DefaultIfEmpty(), (group, user) =>
                new
                {
                    group.notice,
                    user
                })
                .GroupJoin(context.Likes, noticeDto => noticeDto.notice.Id, like => like.ItemId, (noticeDto, likes) => new { noticeDto, likes })
                .Select((group) =>
                new NoticeDto
                {
                    CreatedByName = (group.noticeDto.user == null ? "" : group.noticeDto.user.FullName),
                    Id = group.noticeDto.notice.Id,                 
                    Liked = group.likes != null ? group.likes.Any(w => w.CreatedBy == userId) : false,
                });
```

This is the error I get:

> Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .LeftJoin(
> outer: DbSet
> .AsQueryable(),
> inner: notice => notice.CreatedBy,
> outerKeySelector: user => user.Id,
> innerKeySelector: (notice, user) => new {
> notice = notice,
> user = user
> })
> .GroupJoin(
> outer: DbSet,
> inner: noticeDto => noticeDto.notice.Id,
> outerKeySelector: like => like.ItemId,
> innerKeySelector: (noticeDto, likes) => new {
> noticeDto = noticeDto,
> likes = likes
> })'
> by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core.

Can anyone help me achieve what I need?.. Thank you.

**Notice**

```
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

**User**

```
 public Guid Id { get; set; }
 public string FullName{ get; set; }
```

**Like**

```
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like's ItemId is Notice's Id? Notice's and Like's CreatedBy is User's Id?

If so, try this.

```
return context.notices.Include(x => x.Users)
                      .Include(x => x.Likes)
                      .Include("Likes.Users");
```

### Database

[image]

### Result

[image]

### EDITED

As you do not have foreign key and relationship, then you can try this

```
var users = context.Users;
        
return context.notices.Select(x => new Notice() 
{
     Id = x.Id,
     CreatedBy = x.CreatedBy, 
     Users = users.Where(y => y.Id == x.CreatedBy).FirstOrDefault(), 
     Likes = context.Likes.Where(y => y.ItemId == x.Id)
                    .Select(y => new Likes()
                    {
                        Id = y.Id,
                        CreatedBy = y.CreatedBy,
                        ItemId = y.ItemId,
                        Users = users.Where(z => z.Id == y.CreatedBy).FirstOrDefault()
                    }).ToList()
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Asherguru for your comment. Your first sentence is correct. But i am not using CreatedBy or ItemId as foreign key .. it's just guid. So I don't think it is possible to Include this. To do so I would need to have linking table for it. I thought it is not necessary. Also I don't need to take care about likes and notices when user is deleted.

Comment: Can check "EDITED". Anyway, if you don't need to take care of likes and notices when user is deleted, you just simply add new column "IsDeleted" in user table. When user is deleted, change IsDeleted = 1. Then in Notice's UI and Likes's UI, user name will be like "Name1 (deleted)"

Comment: Yes.. you can achieve it like this.. but I don't think its effective.. you are getting all likes from database. And then for each like you are getting user (I believe it will result in separate calls for each like)

Comment: Updated. you can check it.

Comment: o.O this looks good.. how is this possible? I don't need joins when I use Select? This code will create one query to DB?

Comment: can use join also. it works same as this code. if you prefer using join, you can use it. i never try create query.

Comment: Yes of course and thank you! I did some changes because I just need full name from user and not all likes but just bool if notice was liked by specific user. But with your help it was easy! I am still shocked that I don't need to use Joins here and all what I need is to use Select :)

Comment: Glad to hear about it.